# Two lines from Bibara bibara (Japanese song): do they even make sense?

Tags: grammar, translation

[Bibara bibara](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nukTlm4aSE8) is a Japanese song, so you might be wondering why I am asking on Korean SE. At a certain point, the lyrics go:

> ヨボセヨペゴパヨチキンピリョヘヨ
>
> Yoboseyopegopayochikinpiryoheyo

And further on, a slight variation:

> ヨボセヨペゴパヨメロンピリョヘヨ
>
> Yoboseyopegopayomeronpiryoheyo

I recognize "yoboseyo" as 여보세요, "hello". Also, I saw a translation somewhere going `私はチキンが大好き` or the likes. That means "I really like chicken". "chikin" is recognizable, and indeed 치킨 means chicken. And 멜론 (mellon, Elvish for "friends" :) ) means melon, which is what the other line had in its translation `私はメロンが大好き`. Then I found 필요해요 (piryo haeyo) means "[I] need". So I have all the reasons in the world to think this apparent gibberish is actually Korean. I partially Hangul-ify it:

> 여보세요 ペゴパヨ 치킨 피료해요
>
> Yeoboseyo pegopayo chikin piryo haeyo
>
> 여보세요 ペゴパヨ 멜론 피료해요
>
> Yeoboseyo pegopayo mellon piryo haeyo

But pegopayo? The best I could come up with is `paego` (Conjunction form of `paeda`, "to chop/split") + `payo` (Informal Polite Indicative Present form of `pada`, "to dig"). But does that make any sense? If so, what does it mean? And do these whole sentences make sense or am I forcing an interpretation to actual Gibberish which only by chance resembles Korean words?

Comment: Well I'm not really sure about a lot of it, but I can tell you that 치킨 is just a pronunciation of the English word chicken, and it's only used in some cases. The korean word for chicken is 덝

Comment: @MaxEhrlich As in this case for example :). Anyways, that Korean word. "dalg" in direct transliteration. How is it actually pronounced?

Comment: it's pronounced 덕 in isolation, your transliteration is not correct (I don't like romanization but i guess it would be deok).

Comment: Whoops I actually miscorrected that. The individual jamo are d-eo-l-g. The l is mute. So we get deog. But perhaps ending stops are transliterated with voiceless consonants, so deok, not deog.

Comment: And the miscorrection is [Wiktionary's fault](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%EB%8B%AD#Korean).

Comment: that's correct 받침 are (almost?) always stops so they are romanized as such

Comment: Probably unreleased stops. Point is, ㄱ is transliterated "g" (voiced stop) for spelling convenience when in syllable-initial position. In syllable-final position I guess the spelling convenience vanishes (no need to distinguish ㄱ-ㄲ-ㅋ there), so all those are probably transliterated k (voiceless stop). Naturally, ㄱ is voiceless and ㅋ voiceless aspirated, none is voiced.

Comment: I actually spelled that wrong it is 닭

Comment: So d-a-l-g => dak, as Wiktionary says.

Comment: Korean words in Japanese song?

Comment: Apparently yes @Phonics. Or Sonic the Hedgehog :).

Comment: @MickG Haha, My name is an inside joke made in English Lang U.

Comment: @Phonics then again, seen as the title is an incomplete (and thus cut meaningless) Italian sentence, I wouldn't be too surprised to see two Korean sentences in this song…

Comment: Bibara is a transcription of "viva la", literally "long live the".

Comment: @MickG Artistic License, amiright

Comment: She might've been calling food delivery to get some food out of hunger…….

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I recognize "yoboseyo" as 여보세요, "hello"

This is correct, within the context of answering the phone.

> But pegopayo?

This is most likely 배고파요, "I'm hungry."

Comment: Oh right, yeoboseyo is the phone-answering hello. The greeting is annyeonghaseyo. The songwriter probably confused them.

Comment: The standard Korean romanization suggests `ㅂ` to be always `b`, on the other hand, phonetically `ㅂ` at the first of a sentence sounds /p/, which is voiceless (unvoiced). So it's technically not a _wrong_ transcription.

Answer (score 2):

To add to dotVezz' answer, 치킨 필요 해요 would be 'I need chicken'! 필요하다 means 'there is a necessity of', or 'I need...'